# How to make wicd set dhcp-based routing?

Tags: debian, route

I have a Beaglebone (Debian) with two network interfaces: eth0, usb0.

- usb0 is enabled by ifup from the system start (and used by udhcpd later)
- eth0 is started by wicd when users connects a cable

Here is routng table:

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.7.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 usb0
```

The routing table does not work, eth0 should be routed via 192.168.0.1 gateway.

How could I make wicd

- get a gateway via dhcp,
- set up the gateway (and the route) for its interface.

I can do this in post-connection scripts or statically. I wonder if things can be done simpler via correct configuration of configs like wired-settings.conf?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot add something for a dynamic interface, you can remove the conflict from the static one. `usb0` was statically defined in `/etc/network/interfaces` It is possible to delete a default gateway for `usb0` via post-up, then you get the one from `wicd` correctly.

```
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.252
    gateway 192.168.7.1
    post-up route del default dev usb0
```